# Code runs but doesn't update database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

This code is supposed to save some values in textboxes to a specific row. The code runs just fine with no hiccups, but refuses to actually update the database no matter what I do.

```
try
{
    using (var con = new OleDbConnection())
    {
        con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\User\Desktop\esoft\gym\gym\bin\Debug\Clients.accdb;";
        con.Open();

        using (var com = new OleDbCommand())
        {
             com.Connection = con;
             com.CommandText = "UPDATE gym SET BMI = @bmi and Health = @health and weight_change_to_healthy_bmi = @weight WHERE ID = @id";

             com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bmi", bmi.Text);
             com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@health", health.Text);
             com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weight", change.Text);
             com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id.Text);

             com.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
     }

     MessageBox.Show("Saved");
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Not saved: " + ex.Message);
 }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you ran this query outside your code? What do you mean by "refuses to actually update the database"? Any exceptions thrown?

Comment: no exceptions. the code runs clean. but no data is added to the database.

Comment: update columns are delimited with `,` not `'and'` so `SET BMI = @bmi, Health = @health, weight_change_to_healthy_bmi = @weight WHERE`

Comment: @iboss have you tried running the same query with the values that you're passing in Management Studio (I assume it's a MS SQL database) ?

Comment: using "," instead of "and" worked. thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

As Alex [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657253/code-runs-but-wont-update-database#comment57059796_34657253), `SET` part needs `,` instead of `AND` for multiple columns.

Check [`UPDATE` syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)<sup>1</sup>;

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

But I wanna say a few things more;

- Don't use `AddWithValue` as much as you can. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload to specify your parameter type and it's size.
- Open your connection just before you execute your command. That means, you should open your connection just before your `ExecuteNonQuery` line.
- Based on it's name, `ID` column *should* be some numeric value instead of character. Consider to change it's type or consider to change it's column name that refers some character typed column  name.

1: <sub>I know I  know.. a w3school link</sub>

Comment: It is certainly worth knowing the implications of `.AddWithValue` vs. `.Add` but fortunately they are not much of a concern with an Access database because all Text columns are VarWChar and all Date/Time columns are DateTime.